# Clone sharepoint list view

Tags: list, list-view, 2013, community

Sharepoint 2013 discussions list has a view named "Flat", but it is uneditable. I have to add additional fields in the list and display those fields in Flat view. I tried creating another view of Flat view type but that view is also not displaying the fields that I marked.

So is there is a way to clone this view as editable? I tried cloning that view but the view that is getting created also cannot be edited. This is the code I used to clone the view:

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("url");
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
SPList List = web.Lists["Discussions List"];
SPView thisView = List.Views["Flat"];
thisView = thisView.Clone("Testing", 100, true, false);
thisView.Update();
```

Please give me your feedbacks

Thank You

Comment: Are you getting error in this code? If yes, which type of error...

Comment: @Viraj Gorajia above code is working. Problem is im cloning a view that cannot be edited so the view getting created also uneditable. Is there is a way to clone this uneditable view as a editable view??

Comment: I tried your code. It is working. but i am not able to see another view like flat view, testing vie. Because Subject view is top level view. When open another view, it redirect to subject view(AllItems.aspx).

Comment: @Viraj Gorajia yeah you are right, to view the Flat view you first go to Manage discussions and click a discussion that you created so it'll display all the replies of that specific discussion in Management view there you can change the view to Flat view.

Comment: Thanx @Justin Roy, Your problem is that you have no seen field which is added in flat view?

Comment: @Viraj Gorajia yeah i couldn't see all the fields that I added in that view.. you know how do display those fields??

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

[image: Write code in code ascx.cs file]

Deploy this solution.. And add this web part.. One view is created shown as "Discussion".
It will show all fields which are added in Flat view.

[image: Discussion View]